# defer pipe process to background after text match

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

So I have a bash command to start a server and it outputs some lines before getting to the point where it outputs something like "Server started, Press Control+C to exit". How do I pipe this output so when this line occurs i put this process in the background and continue with another script/function (i.e to do stuff that needs to wait until the server starts such as run tests)

I want to end up with 3 functions

- start_server
- run_tests
- stop_server

I've got something along the lines of:

```
function read_server_output{
    while read data; do
        printf "$data"
        if [[ $data == "Server started, Press Control+C to exit" ]]; then
            # do something here to put server process in the background
            # so I can run another function
        fi
    done
}

function start_server{
    # start the server and pipe its output to another function to check its running
    start-server-command | read_server_output
}

function run_test{
    # do some stuff
}

function stop_server{
    # stop the server
}

# run the bash script code
start_server()
run_tests()
stop_tests()
```

related question possibly [SH/BASH - Scan a log file until some text occurs, then exit. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587797/sh-bash-scan-a-log-file-until-some-text-occurs-then-exit-how/2588080#2588080)

Thanks in advance I'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 4):

First, a note on terminology...

"Background" and "foreground" are controlling-terminal concepts, i.e., they have to do with what happens when you type <kbd>ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+Z</kbd>, etc. (which process gets the signal), whether a process can read from the terminal device (a "background" process gets a `SIGTTIN` that by default causes it to stop), and so on.

It seems clear that this has little to do with what you want to achieve.  Instead, you have an ill-behaved program (or suite of programs) that needs some special coddling: when the server is first started, it needs some hand-holding up to some point, after which it's OK.  The hand-holding can stop once it outputs some text string (see your related question for that, or the technique below).

There's a big potential problem here: a lot of programs, when their output is redirected to a pipe or file, produce *no* output until they have printed a "block" worth of output, or are exiting.  If this is the case, a simple:

```
start-server-command | cat
```

won't print the line you're looking for (so that's a quick way to tell whether you will have to work around this issue as well).  If so, you'll need something like [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), which is an entirely different way to achieve what you want.

Assuming that's not a problem, though, let's try an entirely-in-shell approach.

What you need is to run the `start-server-command` and save the process-ID so that you can (eventually) send it a `SIGINT` signal (as <kbd>ctrl+C</kbd> would if the process *were* "in the foreground", but you're doing this from a script, not from a controlling terminal, so there's no key the script can press).  Fortunately `sh` has a syntax just for this.

First let's make a temporary file:

```
#! /bin/sh
# myscript - script to run server, check for startup, then run tests

TMPFILE=$(mktemp -t myscript) || exit 1    # create /tmp/myscript.<unique>
trap "rm -f $TMPFILE" 0 1 2 3 15           # arrange to clean up when done
```

Now start the server and save its PID:

```
start-server-command > $TMPFILE &          # start server, save output in file
SERVER_PID=$!                              # and save its PID so we can end it

trap "kill -INT $SERVER_PID; rm -f $TMPFILE" 0 1 2 3 15 # adjust cleanup
```

Now you'll want to scan through `$TMPFILE` until the desired output appears, as in the other question.  Because this requires a certain amount of polling you should insert a delay.  It's also probably wise to check whether the server has failed and terminated without ever getting to the "started" point.

```
while ! grep '^Server started, Press Control+C to exit$' >/dev/null; do
    # message has not yet appeared, is server still starting?
    if kill -0 $SERVER_PID 2>/dev/null; then
        # server is running; let's wait a bit and try grepping again
        sleep 1 # or other delay interval
    else
        echo "ERROR: server terminated without starting properly" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

(Here `kill -0` is used to test whether the process still exists; if not, it has exited.  The "cleanup" `kill -INT` will produce an error message, but that's probably OK.  If not, either redirect that `kill` command's error-output, or adjust the cleanup or do it manually, as seen below.)

At this point, the server is running and you can do your tests.  When you want it to exit as if the user hit <kbd>ctrl+C</kbd>, send it a `SIGINT` with `kill -INT`.

Since there's a `kill -INT` in the `trap` set for when the script exits (0) as well as when it's terminated by `SIGHUP` (1), `SIGINT` (2), `SIGQUIT` (3), and `SIGTERM` (15)—that's the:

```
trap "do some stuff" 0 1 2 3 15
```

part—you can simply let your script exit at this point, unless you want to specifically wait for the server to exit too.  If you want that, perhaps:

```
kill -INT $SERVER_PID; rm -f $TMPFILE   # do the pre-arranged cleanup now
trap - 0 1 2 3 15                       # don't need it arranged anymore
wait $SERVER_PID                        # wait for server to finish exit
```

would be appropriate.

(Obviously none of the above is tested, but that's the general framework.)

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to start it in the background and block on reading its output.  Something like:

```
{ start-server-command & } | {
  while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    echo "$line" | grep -q 'Server started' && break
  done
  cat &
}
echo script continues here after server outputs 'Server started' message
```

But this is a pretty ugly hack.  It would be better if the server could be modified to perform a more specific action which the script could wait for.

Comment: That should work too, and avoids the polling issue with my method.  It might be better to hide the server's output though, as with the temp-file approach.  (But I think we both agree, the "best" method is to fix up the server :-) )

Comment: Definitely fixing the server is the right approach.  As you mention in your answer, buffering is also an issue, and my terrible hack does not deal with that at all.

Comment: what's the `cat &` for?

Comment: @TomRoggero The `cat &` is there so that data from `start-server-command` does not just get discarded.  The `while/read` loop echos the output until the 'Server started' line is seen, and the `cat &`  writes all the rest.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you!! <3

Comment: @WilliamPursell how do I obtain the `PID=$!` for the start-server-command? putting it inside `{ start server & }` seems to not work

Comment: @TomRoggero Best practice would be to not do any of this!  But, if you need the pid of start-server-command you could either inspect the output of `jobs -l`, or parse the output of `ps`, or write the pid into a pidfile.